# Pourquoi « où » en lieu et place de « quand » ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, conjonctions, pronoms-relatifs

Dans la proposition suivante, je lis :

> [Le jour **où** le vote est devenu secret](http://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite-france/2013/07/09/01016-20130709ARTFIG00448-le-jour-o-le-vote-est-devenu-secret.php)
>
> The day **when** voting has become secret

ou **où** a le sens de **quand**.

Pourquoi **où**, et pas **quand** dans cette situation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il ne faut pas confondre

> Il est parti quand le vote est devenu secret

où *quand* est une conjonction de subordination, qui introduit la proposition subordonnée conjonctive circonstancielle de temps « quand le vote est devenu secret » avec

> Il est parti le jour où le vote est devenu secret

où *où* est un *pronom* relatif, qui introduit la subordonnée relative « où le vote est devenu secret » et dont l'antécédent est le nom *jour*.

La différence ici est que *quand* n'est pas un pronom relatif, donc ne peut pas introduire une proposition subordonnée relative.